# How to pass values from an array to filter clause while hitting a url

Tags: javascript, api, rest

I have the below student values in an array

```
var arr=['sam','peter','alex']
```

Now I am hitting an endpoint where in I need to filter out the values based on the student names as follows.

```
***************/$format=json&$filter=name eq 'sam' or name eq 'peter' or name eq 'alex'&$select=id,address
```

getData is a custom function to connect to db and performs odata call
Below is the implementation I have used.

```
getData([
                    `/student_details`,
                    `?$format=json`,
                    `&$filter=name eq '${arr}'`,
                   `&$select=id,address`
                ])
```

the length of the names array is not constant and it keeps varying.
The above piece of code doesn't work and instead the url is framed as

```
***************/$format=json&$filter=name eq 'sam,peter,alex'&$select=id,address
```

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use declare a variable `query` that later on you will use in your `getData` function:

```js
var arr=['sam','peter','alex'];

var query = arr.map(e => `name eq "${e}" `).join('or ');

console.log(query);

getData([
    `/student_details`,
    `?$format=json`,
    `&$filter='${query}'`,
    `&$select=id,address`
]);
```

`